# Laravel- store json type null data as [null]

Tags: php, mysql, json, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to store json type data in my database.

migration:

```
$table->json('email_signature')->nullable();
```

Model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'email_signature' => 'array'
];
```

Controller:

```
$system->email_signature = $request->input('email_signature');
```

Data is storing correctly, but when $request is empty, in database it is stored as [null]. If is was NULL then I could make a query using whereNotNull to find if it is null or not. Can it be stored as NULL? Or, how can I catch that [null] value in a query to find if it is null or not?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to use `json_decode(email_signature)` and then check if it is null.

Comment: use json_decode in controller? If i use json_decode to store data then it gives this error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. Besides, I want to check if it is null through eloquent.